# Assembly Language Questions regarding microprocessor pins

Tags: discussion

I have a question related to the assembly language. But its not really related to programming. Its related to the high and low states of the pins in some specific clock cycles or time cycles in the 8086 processor. Should such questions be asked on SO or programmers? Or shouldn't they be asked at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a **how** question, the Stack Overflow. If it's a **why** question, then Programmers.SE. There's also [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), which explicitly welcomes questions about electronics and "bare-metal" applications.

Comment: The how/why distinction is extremely important. Keep SO concrete!

Answer (score 7):

I would try the [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site, it sounds like the best fit.